# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysqldump, errors, error-handling

I know this might be a duplicate of some other posts. But those solutions didn't work for me and I've lot of issues within those answers. Neither could I comment nor post in there, I'm posting a question.

In my case, I logged into mysql as 'root' and tried to import a sql file into the database. I then exited, did nothing and when again tried to login with the same user. But this time it was showing as

```
bash-2.05$ mysql -u root -p                 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And I tried all different solutions(suggestions from other posts) like `mysql -u root -ppwd -h127.0.0.1` `mysql -u root -ppwd --protocol=TCP`. These suggestions didn't work for me. I couldn't login as the root and without that I will not be having permissions to change any privileges. I'm sure user and password are the correct ones.

Apart from all this, I'm using this database for a drupal website. The website gives me an error as

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/apache2/htdocs/website/includes/lock.inc).
```

I couldn't trace what's going wrong with this.

Comment: Examine the source sql file you ran.  Did it contain anything like a mysql.users table or any GRANT, set password or create user queries?  It's possible you blew out your root account credentials with that.

Comment: ya, it has mysql.users table or GRANT. It may be the reason. What if I delete that particular database? Does it work?

Comment: See the link in my answer below on how to restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to restart the mysql daemon you can follow the mysql [directions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html) for recovering your root account.

Comment: I didn't find any of these directories `/var/lib/mysql/` `/var/run/mysqld/` and `/usr/local/mysql/data/` in my server.

Comment: Do a search for the mysqld programme from the root (you need the machine root password) - sudo find . -name "mysqld".

Comment: No I tried using the command, but no result.

Comment: Find the mysqld in your processlist. Run sudo lsof -p PID  where PID is the process id of your mysqld process.  This should show you file handles it has open

Comment: @atxdba I didn't find the file with name mysqld in the processlist. Do you have any idea, usually where it will be??